# Unit test Case - MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

This is method to Convert `String[]` To `String`.

```
private string ConvertStringArrayToString(System.String[] array)
{

    string result = string.Join("<br />", array);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

This is unit test case method for the above method.

```
[TestMethod] 
public void ConvertStringArrayToString_shouldReturnString()
{
    string returnedString = null;


    PrivateObject o = new PrivateObject(typeof(DemoClass));
    System.String[] array = new System.String[] 
    {
        "Index0","Index0","Index0","Index0"
    };

    returnedString = (string)Convert.ChangeType((o.Invoke("ConvertStringArrayToString", array)), typeof(string));

}
```

This results in missing method exception.

I found the error is in Passing parameter i.e. `string[]`

But when I replace method access specifier as `public`, the test case works without error!

Please help why method cannot be able to access when it is `private` and `string[]`.

Comment: Aside from the reflection problem, why are you testing a private method? Private methods shouldn't be unit tested. Don't you test the method through the public interface of your class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `array` is being passed directly as the argument for the `object[]` parameter, whereas you really want it to be wrapped so it's just the first argument in an array of arguments. So I'd write this:

```
string[] array = { "Index0", "Index0", "Index0", "Index0" };
object[] args = { array };
var result = o.Invoke("ConvertStringArrayToString", args);
string returnedString = (string) result;
```

(There's no need to declare `returnedString` earlier, and you don't need to use `Convert.ChangeType` - a cast should be fine.)